# Python3 cv2: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor only in a script file

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, openai-gym

this error `error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor` is only in my script, but if I ran the code in an IPython shell everthing works fine. The code is used to reduce dimensions for a DQN (Deeq-Q-network) running with `openai-gym` and I have no idea why this is not in my script but in my shell. 
I add a comment were the error appers. Full code can be added if needed.

Part of the code:

```
def preprocess(self,inp):
    inp=cv2.resize(inp,(84, 110))
    inp=cv2.cvtColor(inp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    inp=inp[26:110,:]
    ret,obs=cv2.threshold(inp,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return np.reshape(obs,(84,84,1))

def Q_Learning(self,modell_path="Your path here"):
    observation=self.env.reset()
    for i in range(self.itertime):
        observation=self.preprocess(observation)#!Error appers here!
        if np.random.rand()<=self.random_move_prop:
            action=np.random.randint(low=0,high=self.env.action_space.n)
        else:
            action=self.model.predict(observation)
            action=np.argmax(action)
        new_observation, reward, done, info=self.env.step(action)
        new_observation=self.preprocess(new_observation)
        self.storage.append([observation,action,reward,new_observation,done])
        observation=new_observation
        if done:
            self.env.reset()
```

Comment: The error basically tells you that it is not an image with 3 or 4 channels (needed to the conversion from BGR to GRAY). Most probably the error is loading the image (which is not in the snippet of code supplied)

Comment: @api55 the "image" is the result of gyms env.reset() method, often called observation. This array should be useable (worked in my IPython shell)

Comment: well, an easy test would be to do:  `print(type(inp))` and `print(inp.dtype)` and `print(inp.shape)` at the beginning of preprocess function. This way you may not for sure what are you passing to the function :)

Comment: @api55 thanks that was very helpfull. The second input was the previous output. I will fix it, thank you very much

Comment: @api55 So after "fixing" my interpreter returns:  3221226505 (0xc0000409) this only. No error, no failure, nothing. Any idea what this is? I read about a buffer overflow?!